# How do I get a plist as a Dictionary in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am playing around with Apple's new **Swift** programming language and have some problems...

Currently I'm trying to read a plist file, in Objective-C I would do the following to get the content as a NSDictionary:

```
NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Config" ofType:@"plist"];
NSDictionary *dict = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:filePath];
```

How do I get a plist as a Dictionary in Swift?

I assume I can get the path to the plist with:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Config", ofType: "plist")
```

When this works (If it's correct?): How do I get the content as a Dictionary?

Also a more general question:

Is it OK to use the default **NS*** classes? I think so...or am I missing something? As far as I know the default framework **NS*** classes are still valid and alright to use?

Comment: The answer is no longer valid, could you please select the Ashok's answer?

Comment: Recommend clarifying that this question relates to Bundle. That is because the solution varies distinctly Bundle or non-Bundle.

Answer (score 62, accepted):

In ***swift 3.0*** Reading from Plist.

```
func readPropertyList() {
        var propertyListFormat =  PropertyListSerialization.PropertyListFormat.xml //Format of the Property List.
        var plistData: [String: AnyObject] = [:] //Our data
        let plistPath: String? = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "data", ofType: "plist")! //the path of the data
        let plistXML = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: plistPath!)!
        do {//convert the data to a dictionary and handle errors.
            plistData = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: plistXML, options: .mutableContainersAndLeaves, format: &propertyListFormat) as! [String:AnyObject]

        } catch {
            print("Error reading plist: \(error), format: \(propertyListFormat)")
        }
    }
```

*Read More
[HOW TO USE PROPERTY LISTS (.PLIST) IN SWIFT](https://makeapppie.com/2016/02/11/how-to-use-property-lists-plist-in-swift/#comment-17173).*

Comment: Askok. Lost many hours trying to find an answer to this today on this! THANK YOU!! This worked perfectly!!!

Answer (score 305):

You can still use NSDictionaries in Swift:

**For Swift 4**

```
 var nsDictionary: NSDictionary?
 if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Config", ofType: "plist") {
    nsDictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
 }
```

**For Swift 3+**

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Config", ofType: "plist"),
   let myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path){
    // Use your myDict here
}
```

And older versions of Swift

```
var myDict: NSDictionary?
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Config", ofType: "plist") {
    myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
}
if let dict = myDict {
    // Use your dict here
}
```

The NSClasses are still available and perfectly fine to use in Swift. I think they'll probably want to shift focus to swift soon, but currently the swift APIs don't have all the functionality of the core NSClasses.

Comment: hmm when i try using that code you provided, i get the error : xxx does not have a member named dict

Comment: it works fine in playground tho. just not in my swift document

Comment: how does it looks like if Array?

Comment: Looks like `mainBundle()` is just `main` in Swift 3

Comment: what about swift 4 ?

Comment: The question was about swift. Swift has its own dictionary types. But you use `NSDictionary` instead

Comment: This answer is outdated. Even in Swift 3 you **should not** use `NSArray/NSDictionary` at all to read property list data. `PropertyListSerialization` (and in Swift 4 alternatively the `Codable` protocol) is the appropriate API. It provides modern error handling and the data can be converted directly to native Swift collection types.

Comment: Using NSDictionaries comes at a performance penalty when you convert them to a Swift Dictionary.

Answer (score 143):

This is what I do if I want to convert a .plist to a Swift dictionary:

###### For Swift 3.0:

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Config", ofType: "plist"),
   let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String: AnyObject] {
    // use swift dictionary as normal
}
```

---

###### For Swift 2.0:

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Config", ofType: "plist"),
   dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String: AnyObject] {
    // use swift dictionary as normal
}
```

###### For Swift 1:

```
if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Config", ofType: "plist") {
  if let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
    // use swift dictionary as normal
  }
}
```

Comment: I think this is "the most correct" answer of the bunch until there is a native swift way to do this.

Comment: This answer is outdated. In Swift 3 you **should not** use `NSArray/NSDictionary` at all to read property list data. `PropertyListSerialization` (and in Swift 4 alternatively the `Codable` protocol) is the appropriate API. It provides modern error handling and the data can be converted directly to native Swift collection types.

Answer (score 71):

## Swift 4.0

You can now use the Decodable protocol to Decode a .plist into a custom struct. I will go over a basic example, for more complicated .plist structures I recommend reading up on Decodable/Encodable (a good resource is here: https://benscheirman.com/2017/06/swift-json/).

First setup your struct into the format of your .plist file. For this example I will consider a .plist with a root level Dictionary and 3 entries: 1 String with key "name", 1 Int with key "age", and 1 Boolean with key "single". Here is the struct:

```
struct Config: Decodable {
    private enum CodingKeys: String, CodingKey {
        case name, age, single
    }

    let name: String
    let age: Int
    let single: Bool
}
```

Simple enough. Now the cool part. Using the PropertyListDecoder class we can easily parse the .plist file into an instantiation of this struct:

```
func parseConfig() -> Config {
    let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Config", withExtension: "plist")!
    let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
    let decoder = PropertyListDecoder()
    return try! decoder.decode(Config.self, from: data)
}
```

Not much more code to worry about, and its all in Swift. Better yet we now have an instantiation of the Config struct that we can easily use:

```
let config = parseConfig()
print(config.name) 
print(config.age)
print(config.single)
```

This Prints the value for the "name", "age", and "single" keys in the .plist.

Comment: That's the best answer for Swift 4. But why not `Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Config", withExtension: "plist")` and get rid of `URL(fileURLWithPath`? And as the file is required to exist (at design / compile time) all values can be force unwrapped. The code must not crash if everything is designed properly.

Comment: @vadian Sure you can use `url(forResource: "Config", withExtension: "plist")` I was just matching what the OP did in their code as a point of comparison. As far as force unwrapping everything, I try to err on the side of caution. I think that is a fundamental question for Swift in general. I'd rather know exactly what my code will do in any situation than crash.

Comment: 1) Please don't adopt bad habits if there is a more appropriate API. 2) That's one of the few cases where a forced crash discovers a design error. Any file in the bundle is required to be present at compile time and cannot be changed at  runtime because all files are code-signed. Once again: *The code must not crash if everything is designed properly*.

Comment: Yea you know your right. Didn't realize that was the case with Bundle resources.

Comment: One other thing to note: for completeness I added the CodingKeys enum, however since this case is pretty simple where var names match the plist names you can omit it if you wish.

Comment: @NaveenGeorgeThoppan if you use this example as your dictionary then it would simply be `decoder.decode([Config].self, from: data)`. (Notice the brackets around [Config])

Comment: @ekreloff those brackets were just what I needed to make my deserializing work. Man I tried everything else.

Comment: It looks like reading Info.plist with this will get variable substitutions in info.plist. For example, CFBundleDisplayName = $(PRODUCT_NAME) will be read exactly as $(PRODUCT_NAME), not the value behind the variable.

Answer (score 22):

This answer uses Swift native objects rather than NSDictionary.

### Swift 3.0

```
//get the path of the plist file
guard let plistPath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "level1", ofType: "plist") else { return }
//load the plist as data in memory
guard let plistData = FileManager.default.contents(atPath: plistPath) else { return }
//use the format of a property list (xml)
var format = PropertyListSerialization.PropertyListFormat.xml
//convert the plist data to a Swift Dictionary
guard let  plistDict = try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: plistData, options: .mutableContainersAndLeaves, format: &format) as? [String : AnyObject] else { return }
//access the values in the dictionary 
if let value = plistDict["aKey"] as? String {
  //do something with your value
  print(value)
}
//you can also use the coalesce operator to handle possible nil values
var myValue = plistDict["aKey"] ?? ""
```

Comment: Is there a concise version to this?

Answer (score 19):

I have been working with Swift 3.0 and wanted to contribute an answer for the updated syntax. Additionally, and possibly more importantly, I am using the **PropertyListSerialization** object to do the heavy lifting, which is a lot more flexible than just using the NSDictionary as it allows for an Array as the root type of the plist.

Below is a screenshot of the plist I am using. It is a *little* complicated, so as to show the power available, but this will work for any allowable combination of plist types.

[image: Sample plist file]
As you can see I am using an Array of String:String dictionaries to store a list of website names and their corresponding URL.

I am using the **PropertyListSerialization** object, as mentioned above, to do the heavy lifting for me. Additionally, Swift 3.0 has become more "Swifty" so all of the object names have lost the "NS" prefix.

```
let path = Bundle.main().pathForResource("DefaultSiteList", ofType: "plist")!
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
let data = try! Data(contentsOf: url)
let plist = try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: .mutableContainers, format: nil)
```

After the above code runs `plist` will be of type `Array<AnyObject>`, but we know what type it really is so we can cast it to the correct type:

```
let dictArray = plist as! [[String:String]]
// [[String:String]] is equivalent to Array< Dictionary<String, String> >
```

And now we can access the various properties of our Array of String:String Dictionaries in a natural way. *Hopefully to convert them into actual strongly typed structs or classes ;)*

```
print(dictArray[0]["Name"])
```

Answer (score 11):

**Swift 5**

If you want to fetch specific value for some key then we can use below extension which uses **infoDictionary** property on Bundle.

`Bundle.main.infoDictionary` can be used to get all `info.plist` values in the form dictionary and so we can directly query using `object(forInfoDictionaryKey: key)` method on Bundle

```
extension Bundle {
    static func infoPlistValue(forKey key: String) -> Any? {
        guard let value = Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: key) else {
           return nil
        }
        return value
    }
}
```

**Usage**

```
guard let apiURL = Bundle.infoPlistValue(forKey: "API_URL_KEY") as? String else { return }
```

Answer (score 9):

Converted into a convenience extension via Nick's answer:

```
extension Dictionary {
    static func contentsOf(path: URL) -> Dictionary<String, AnyObject> {
        let data = try! Data(contentsOf: path)
        let plist = try! PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: .mutableContainers, format: nil)

        return plist as! [String: AnyObject]
    }
}
```

usage:

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "plistName", ofType: "plist")!
let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)
let dict = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>.contentsOf(path: url)
```

I'd be willing to bet that it would also work to create a similar extension for Arrays

Comment: This is a decent approach, except for the crashing. The original ObjC method on NSDictionary simply returned nil if decoding failed, if I recall correctly.

Answer (score 8):

It is best to use native dictionaries and arrays because they have been optimized for use with swift. That being said you can use NS... classes in swift and I think this situation warrants that. Here is how you would implement it:

```
var path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Config", ofType: "plist")
var dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
```

So far (in my opinion) this is the easiest and most efficient way to access a plist, but in the future I expect that apple will add more functionality (such as using plist) into native dictionaries.

Comment: As far as you know, has adding plist reading to native dictionaries happened already?

Answer (score 8):

**Swift - Read/Write plist and text file....**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    let fileManager = (NSFileManager .defaultManager())
    let directorys : [String]? = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSSearchPathDirectory.DocumentDirectory,NSSearchPathDomainMask.AllDomainsMask, true) as? [String]

    if (directorys != nil){
        let directories:[String] = directorys!;
        let dictionary = directories[0]; //documents directory


        //  Create and insert the data into the Plist file  ....
        let plistfile = "myPlist.plist"
        var myDictionary: NSMutableDictionary = ["Content": "This is a sample Plist file ........."]
        let plistpath = dictionary.stringByAppendingPathComponent(plistfile);

        if !fileManager .fileExistsAtPath(plistpath){//writing Plist file
            myDictionary.writeToFile(plistpath, atomically: false)
        }
        else{            //Reading Plist file
            println("Plist file found")

            let resultDictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: plistpath)
            println(resultDictionary?.description)
        }


        //  Create and insert the data into the Text file  ....
        let textfile = "myText.txt"
        let sampleText = "This is a sample text file ......... "

        let textpath = dictionary.stringByAppendingPathComponent(textfile);
        if !fileManager .fileExistsAtPath(textpath){//writing text file
            sampleText.writeToFile(textpath, atomically: false, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil);
        } else{
            //Reading text file
            let reulttext  = String(contentsOfFile: textpath, encoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding, error: nil)
            println(reulttext)
        }
    }
    else {
        println("directory is empty")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 8):

**Swift 2.0 :  Accessing Info.Plist**

I have a Dictionary named CoachMarksDictionary  with a boolean value in Info.Plist . I want to access the bool value and make it true.

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Info", ofType: "plist")!
  let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as! [String: AnyObject]

  if let CoachMarksDict = dict["CoachMarksDictionary"] {
       print("Info.plist : \(CoachMarksDict)")

   var dashC = CoachMarksDict["DashBoardCompleted"] as! Bool
    print("DashBoardCompleted state :\(dashC) ")
  }
```

**Writing To Plist:**

From a Custom Plist:- 
(Make from File-New-File-Resource-PropertyList. Added three strings named : DashBoard_New, DashBoard_Draft, DashBoard_Completed)

```
func writeToCoachMarksPlist(status:String?,keyName:String?)
 {
  let path1 = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("CoachMarks", ofType: "plist")
  let coachMarksDICT = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: path1!)! as NSMutableDictionary
  var coachMarksMine = coachMarksDICT.objectForKey(keyName!)

  coachMarksMine  = status
  coachMarksDICT.setValue(status, forKey: keyName!)
  coachMarksDICT.writeToFile(path1!, atomically: true)
 }
```

The method can be called as

```
self.writeToCoachMarksPlist(" true - means user has checked the marks",keyName: "the key in the CoachMarks dictionary").
```

Comment: This is what I was looking out for! Thanks buddy!

Answer (score 7):

Since this answer isn't here yet, just wanted to point out you can also use the infoDictionary property to get the info plist as a dictionary, `Bundle.main.infoDictionary`.

Although something like `Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: kCFBundleNameKey as String)` *may* be faster if you're only interested in a specific item in the info plist.

```
// Swift 4

// Getting info plist as a dictionary
let dictionary = Bundle.main.infoDictionary

// Getting the app display name from the info plist
Bundle.main.infoDictionary?[kCFBundleNameKey as String]

// Getting the app display name from the info plist (another way)
Bundle.main.object(forInfoDictionaryKey: kCFBundleNameKey as String)
```

Answer (score 5):

can actually do it in 1 line

```
    var dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Config", ofType: "plist"))
```

Answer (score 5):

You can read plist in SWIFT Language in this way:

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("PriceList", ofType: "plist")
let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
```

Read Single Dictionary value:

```
let test: AnyObject = dict.objectForKey("index1")
```

If you want to get full multi-dimensional dictionary in plist:

```
let value: AnyObject = dict.objectForKey("index2").objectForKey("date")
```

Here is the plist:

```
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
<key>index2</key>
<dict>
    <key>date</key>
    <string>20140610</string>
    <key>amount</key>
    <string>110</string>
</dict>
<key>index1</key>
<dict>
    <key>amount</key>
    <string>125</string>
    <key>date</key>
    <string>20140212</string>
</dict>
</dict>
</plist>
```

Answer (score 3):

in my case I create a `NSDictionary` called *`appSettings`* and add all needed keys. For this case, the solution is:

```
if let dict = NSBundle.mainBundle().objectForInfoDictionaryKey("appSettings") {
  if let configAppToken = dict["myKeyInsideAppSettings"] as? String {

  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks. `objectForInfoDictionaryKey` was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

**Step 1** : Simple and fastest way to parse plist in swift 3+

```
extension Bundle {

    func parsePlist(ofName name: String) -> [String: AnyObject]? {

        // check if plist data available
        guard let plistURL = Bundle.main.url(forResource: name, withExtension: "plist"),
            let data = try? Data(contentsOf: plistURL)
            else {
                return nil
        }

        // parse plist into [String: Anyobject]
        guard let plistDictionary = try? PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: [], format: nil) as? [String: AnyObject] else {
            return nil
        }

        return plistDictionary
    }
}
```

**Step 2: How to use:**

```
Bundle().parsePlist(ofName: "Your-Plist-Name")
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use that, I create a simple extension for Dictionary in github https://github.com/DaRkD0G/LoadExtension

```
extension Dictionary {
    /**
        Load a Plist file from the app bundle into a new dictionary

        :param: File name
        :return: Dictionary<String, AnyObject>?
    */
    static func loadPlistFromProject(filename: String) -> Dictionary<String, AnyObject>? {

        if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("GameParam", ofType: "plist") {
            return NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
        }
        println("Could not find file: \(filename)")
        return nil
    }
}
```

And you can use that for load

```
/**
  Example function for load Files Plist

  :param: Name File Plist
*/
func loadPlist(filename: String) -> ExampleClass? {
    if let dictionary = Dictionary<String, AnyObject>.loadPlistFromProject(filename) {
        let stringValue = (dictionary["name"] as NSString)
        let intergerValue = (dictionary["score"] as NSString).integerValue
        let doubleValue = (dictionary["transition"] as NSString).doubleValue

        return ExampleClass(stringValue: stringValue, intergerValue: intergerValue, doubleValue: doubleValue)
    }
    return nil
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a bit shorter version, based on @connor 's answer

```
guard let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "GoogleService-Info", ofType: "plist"),
    let myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) else {
    return nil
}

let value = dict.value(forKey: "CLIENT_ID") as! String?
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3.0**

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "config", ofType: "plist") {
    let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)

    // use dictionary
}
```

The easiest way to do this in my opinion.

Answer (score 2):

I've created a simple `Dictionary` initializer that replaces `NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)`. Just remove the `NS`.

```
extension Dictionary where Key == String, Value == Any {

    public init?(contentsOfFile path: String) {
        let url = URL(fileURLWithPath: path)

        self.init(contentsOfURL: url)
    }

    public init?(contentsOfURL url: URL) {
        guard let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url),
            let dictionary = (try? PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, options: [], format: nil) as? [String: Any]) ?? nil
            else { return nil }

        self = dictionary
    }

}
```

You can use it like so:

```
let filePath = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Preferences", ofType: "plist")!
let preferences = Dictionary(contentsOfFile: filePath)!
UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: preferences)
```

Answer (score 2):

Swift 4.0 iOS 11.2.6 list parsed and code to parse it, based on https://stackoverflow.com/users/3647770/ashok-r answer above.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<array>
  <dict>
    <key>identity</key>
    <string>blah-1</string>
    <key>major</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>minor</key>
    <string>1</string>
    <key>uuid</key>
    <string>f45321</string>
    <key>web</key>
    <string>http://web</string>
</dict>
<dict>
    <key>identity</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>major</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>minor</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>uuid</key>
    <string></string>
    <key>web</key>
    <string></string>
  </dict>
</array>
</plist>

do {
   let plistXML = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    var plistData: [[String: AnyObject]] = [[:]]
    var propertyListFormat =  PropertyListSerialization.PropertyListFormat.xml
        do {
            plistData = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: plistXML, options: .mutableContainersAndLeaves, format: &propertyListFormat) as! [[String:AnyObject]]

        } catch {
            print("Error reading plist: \(error), format: \(propertyListFormat)")
        }
    } catch {
        print("error no upload")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's the solution I found:

```
let levelBlocks = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("LevelBlocks", ofType: "plist"))
let test: AnyObject = levelBlocks.objectForKey("Level1")
println(test) // Prints the value of test
```

I set the type of `test` to `AnyObject` to silence a warning about an unexpected inference that could occur.

Also, it has to be done in a class method.

To access and save a specific value of a known type:

```
let value = levelBlocks.objectForKey("Level1").objectForKey("amount") as Int
println(toString(value)) // Converts value to String and prints it
```

Answer (score 0):

I use swift dictionaries but convert them to and from NSDictionaries in my file manager class like so:

```
    func writePlist(fileName:String, myDict:Dictionary<String, AnyObject>){
        let docsDir:String = dirPaths[0] as String
        let docPath = docsDir + "/" + fileName
        let thisDict = myDict as NSDictionary
        if(thisDict.writeToFile(docPath, atomically: true)){
            NSLog("success")
        } else {
            NSLog("failure")
        }

    }
    func getPlist(fileName:String)->Dictionary<String, AnyObject>{
        let docsDir:String = dirPaths[0] as String
        let docPath = docsDir + "/" + fileName
        let thisDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: docPath)
        return thisDict! as! Dictionary<String, AnyObject>
    }
```

This seems the least troubling way to read and write but let's the rest of my code stay as swift as possible.

Answer (score 0):

[Plist](https://github.com/BenziAhamed/Plist) is a simple Swift enum I made for working with property lists.

```
// load an applications info.plist data

let info = Plist(NSBundle.mainBundle().infoDictionary)
let identifier = info["CFBundleIndentifier"].string!
```

More examples:

```
import Plist

// initialize using an NSDictionary
// and retrieve keyed values

let info = Plist(dict)
let name = info["name"].string ?? ""
let age = info["age"].int ?? 0


// initialize using an NSArray
// and retrieve indexed values

let info = Plist(array)
let itemAtIndex0 = info[0].value


// utility initiaizer to load a plist file at specified path
let info = Plist(path: "path_to_plist_file")

// we support index chaining - you can get to a dictionary from an array via
// a dictionary and so on
// don't worry, the following will not fail with errors in case
// the index path is invalid
if let complicatedAccessOfSomeStringValueOfInterest = info["dictKey"][10]["anotherKey"].string {
  // do something
}
else {
  // data cannot be indexed
}

// you can also re-use parts of a plist data structure

let info = Plist(...)
let firstSection = info["Sections"][0]["SectionData"]
let sectionKey = firstSection["key"].string!
let sectionSecret = firstSection["secret"].int!
```

**Plist.swift**

Plist itself is quite simple, here's its listing in case you to refer directly.

```
//
//  Plist.swift
//


import Foundation


public enum Plist {

    case dictionary(NSDictionary)
    case Array(NSArray)
    case Value(Any)
    case none

    public init(_ dict: NSDictionary) {
        self = .dictionary(dict)
    }

    public init(_ array: NSArray) {
        self = .Array(array)
    }

    public init(_ value: Any?) {
        self = Plist.wrap(value)
    }

}


// MARK:- initialize from a path

extension Plist {

    public init(path: String) {
        if let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) {
            self = .dictionary(dict)
        }
        else if let array = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) {
            self = .Array(array)
        }
        else {
            self = .none
        }
    }

}


// MARK:- private helpers

extension Plist {

    /// wraps a given object to a Plist
    fileprivate static func wrap(_ object: Any?) -> Plist {

        if let dict = object as? NSDictionary {
            return .dictionary(dict)
        }
        if let array = object as? NSArray {
            return .Array(array)
        }
        if let value = object {
            return .Value(value)
        }
        return .none
    }

    /// tries to cast to an optional T
    fileprivate func cast<T>() -> T? {
        switch self {
        case let .Value(value):
            return value as? T
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }
}

// MARK:- subscripting

extension Plist {

    /// index a dictionary
    public subscript(key: String) -> Plist {
        switch self {

        case let .dictionary(dict):
            let v = dict.object(forKey: key)
            return Plist.wrap(v)

        default:
            return .none
        }
    }

    /// index an array
    public subscript(index: Int) -> Plist {
        switch self {
        case let .Array(array):
            if index >= 0 && index < array.count {
                return Plist.wrap(array[index])
            }
            return .none

        default:
            return .none
        }
    }

}


// MARK:- Value extraction

extension Plist {

    public var string: String?       { return cast() }
    public var int: Int?             { return cast() }
    public var double: Double?       { return cast() }
    public var float: Float?         { return cast() }
    public var date: Date?         { return cast() }
    public var data: Data?         { return cast() }
    public var number: NSNumber?     { return cast() }
    public var bool: Bool?           { return cast() }


    // unwraps and returns the underlying value
    public var value: Any? {
        switch self {
        case let .Value(value):
            return value
        case let .dictionary(dict):
            return dict
        case let .Array(array):
            return array
        case .none:
            return nil
        }
    }

    // returns the underlying array
    public var array: NSArray? {
        switch self {
        case let .Array(array):
            return array
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

    // returns the underlying dictionary
    public var dict: NSDictionary? {
        switch self {
        case let .dictionary(dict):
            return dict
        default:
            return nil
        }
    }

}


// MARK:- CustomStringConvertible

extension Plist : CustomStringConvertible {
    public var description:String {
        switch self {
        case let .Array(array): return "(array \(array))"
        case let .dictionary(dict): return "(dict \(dict))"
        case let .Value(value): return "(value \(value))"
        case .none: return "(none)"
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

### Swift 3.0

if you want to read a "2-dimensional Array" from .plist, you can try it like this:

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Info", ofType: "plist") {
    if let dimension1 = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) {
        if let dimension2 = dimension1["key"] as? [String] {
            destination_array = dimension2
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you have Info.plist, then use

```
Bundle.main.infoDictionary
```

Answer (score -2):

Simple **struct** to access plist file (Swift 2.0)

```
struct Configuration {      
  static let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Info", ofType: "plist")!
  static let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as! [String: AnyObject]

  static let someValue = dict["someKey"] as! String
}
```

Usage:

```
print("someValue = \(Configuration.someValue)")
```