# Reading pList in swift

Tags: ios, swift

Has anyone figured out how to read a plist into an array or dictionary in Swift? I cannot seem to figure it out. I am used to dictionaryWithContentsOfFile however that doesn't seem to be available in swift.

Comment: Read this page


https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045570/swift-read-plist?rq=1

Answer (score 21):

See the answer to this question: [Swift - Read plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045570/swift-read-plist)

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Config", ofType: "plist")
let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path!)
```