# How do I access an array and it objects within a plist with SWIFT?

Tags: swift, plist, ios8

Good Morning,

I have looked around here and Google but cant seem to find an answer. I have a plist called SoundsList - at the root level its a dictionary (default), the first item is an Array called Sounds and then its items are all strings.

I want to be able to access the items within the array but cant seem to find how to do this.

```
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("SoundsList", ofType: "plist")
let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
```

The above code is what I managed to find so far that gives me the path and the dictionary part - I managed to find this code within another post - [Swift - Read plist](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045570/swift-read-plist)

Regards,

Dave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you are correct

```
//Gives path of plist
let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("SoundsList", ofType: "plist")
//you are intializing dictionary from plist
let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
```

this code gives you dictionary.You can print the contents of dictionary

```
println(dict)
```

As you described the structure of dictinary it should be like that

```
{
 "Sounds":(
            "sound1",
             "sound2"
          )

}
```

So to acess the soundlist you can use

```
  var soundsList = dict["Sounds"]
  println(soundList) //this will print your soundList
```

You can iterate to each object by using

```
for item in soundsList {
   println(item)  //print sound1 and sound2
}
```

You should refer collection types from swift guide https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/mac/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/CollectionTypes.html

Comment: After reading the above and a look at that link, I tweaked it as Xcode was giving 'inference' errors. var soundsList : Array<String> = dict["Sounds"] as Array<String>