# Adding entries to Dictionary (not NSDictionary) from Info.plist

Tags: dictionary, swift, nsdictionary

In the following OS X application, how can I create a Dictionary in a similar way to how I create an NSDictionary?

I suppose I need to find a method on Dictionary that performs the same task as NSDictionary(contentsOfFile:infoPlist) but I am not sure what this Dictionary method is.

```
import Cocoa

class AppDelegate: NSObject, NSApplicationDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var window: NSWindow!

    func applicationDidFinishLaunching(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
        var infoPlist = "/Applications/Calendar.app/Contents/Info.plist"

        var nsDictionary = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile:infoPlist)
        println("nsDictionary = \(nsDictionary)")

        var dictionary = Dictionary<String, String>()
        // TODO: How do I add entries from "infoPlist" to "dictionary"
        // like I do above with the old "nsDictionary"?
        println("dictionary = \(dictionary)")
    }

    func applicationWillTerminate(aNotification: NSNotification?) {
    }
}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Sadly there is no way to do this in native swift dictionaries at the moment. However using NSDictionary is still quite fine.

For more info you can look at [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045570/swift-read-plist)