# Swift plist - Reading item 4

Tags: swift, plist

I want to translate my current program to Swift and I am getting hung up on the simplest things.

I am trying to read a plist [image]

But I want to do this one at a time.

i.e. - if we are trying to call the image candy hearts.jpg  (we obviously need to add the extension jpeg.

This is what I found on on the net.

```
var myDict: NSDictionary?
    if let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("data", ofType: "plist") {
        myDict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)
      //  self.data
    }
    if let dict = myDict {
        // Use your dict here
    }
```

This is what I originally used  iOS6

```
NSString *pathOfDataTitle = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"data" ofType:@"plist"];
NSMutableArray *arrayOfTitle = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:pathOfDataTitle];
self.Datalist = arrayOfTitle;
```

Comment: Please provide your current code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Swift - Read plist](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045570/swift-read-plist)

Comment: And what exactly is your question?

Answer (score 0):

This worked
 var data: NSArray?
 var imagename : String!

```
func readlist(var filename:String) -> NSArray{
    var myDict: NSArray?
    let path = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource(filename, ofType: "plist")

    if (path != nil){
        var val:String
        val=path!;

        myDict = NSArray(contentsOfFile: val)
        var list=myDict;


    }
    if let dict = myDict {
        return myDict!;

    }
    return myDict!;
}
```

}