# send data from viewController to tableViewCell without using segue

Tags: swift, tableview

Hi im trying to pass data between two viewController from different storyBoard . like this i want to pass image and label to tableViewCell without using segue . how can i do it ?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d9xos.jpg)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing Data between View Controllers without segue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49139209/passing-data-between-view-controllers-without-segue)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Passing Data between View Controllers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5210535/passing-data-between-view-controllers)

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the world of stack overflow.

There are many approaches to pass data between viewcontrollers. Most liked are `Delegates` and on `NSNotificationCenter`.

Please have a look at [this](https://learnappmaking.com/pass-data-between-view-controllers-swift-how-to/) article. You will get the idea.