# Retrieving string from UserDefaults not working

Tags: swift, userdefaults

I have created a simple app in Swift that contains a `WebViewControl`. Thanks to a `SettingsBundle` the user is able to specify a URL that is then opened in the WebView. `Root.plist` looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>StringsTable</key>
    <string>Root</string>
    <key>PreferenceSpecifiers</key>
    <array>
        <dict>
            <key>Type</key>
            <string>PSTextFieldSpecifier</string>
            <key>Title</key>
            <string>URL</string>
            <key>Key</key>
            <string>app_url</string>
            <key>DefaultValue</key>
            <string>https://myurl.com</string>
            <key>IsSecure</key>
            <false/>
            <key>KeyboardType</key>
            <string>URL</string>
            <key>AutocapitalizationType</key>
            <string>None</string>
            <key>AutocorrectionType</key>
            <string>No</string>
        </dict>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

This works fine. However when trying to retrieve the `app_url` in Swift I am running in a problem.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    registerSettingsBundle()

    print("retrieving key")
    if let appUrl = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "app_url") {
        print("got it " + appUrl)
    }
}

func registerSettingsBundle(){
    let appDefaults = [String:AnyObject]()
    UserDefaults.standard.register(defaults: appDefaults)
}
```

This prints `retrieving key` to the console, but never the second print statement.

It was working a while ago, but a recent update broke it. What am I doing wrong? Has the API changed somehow? I read [the documentation from Apple on UserDefaults](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/userdefaults), but it hasn't helped me so far.

**Edit regarding `marked as duplicate`**: It is crucial that the user is able to change `app_url` using the Settings app in iOS. Just reading the plist file as a dict is not sufficient. Please excuse me, this is the first time I am experimenting with iOS apps.

Comment: How does the URL get to `UserDefaults` from your `.plist` file?

Comment: Root.plist != UserDefaults. To read from plist: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045570/how-do-i-get-a-plist-as-a-dictionary-in-swift

Comment: @DávidPásztor Please see my edit.

Comment: @dislick why are you registering the app defaults, as you can get the value from sharedDefaults of app bundle.

Comment: @vadian Thank you. I removed the `registerSettingsBundle` function completely, however I am still unable to retrieve the URL. Any other ideas?

Comment: I updated my answer, you could try first `object(forKey` to check if there is a value at all.

Comment: @vadian `if let appUrl = UserDefaults.standard.object(forKey: "app_url") { print("got it") }` does not print `got it` sadly.

Comment: Does the value appear in the settings of the app on the device? If yes you should be able to read it via `UserDefaults`, too.

Comment: @vadian Yes it appears in the settings app on the device. I can even change the value in the plist, re build the app and the new value appears in the settings app.

Answer (score 0):

I reopened the question because it's not a duplicate. The `settings` plist should not opened in code anyway.

The problem is `registerSettingsBundle`. After calling this method the defaults dictionary is empty and retrieving any data will fail. Don't call `registerSettingsBundle` as you declared the default value in the settings bundle.

<strike>`registerSettingsBundle()`</strike>

And as the type is URL use `url(forKey`

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to get data from `plist` so you need to do like this

```
if let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "SettingsBundle", ofType: "plist") {

    //plist contain root as Array
    if let arrayData = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) as? [[String: Any]] {

    }

    //Or plist contain root as Dictionary
    if let dictData = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path) as? [String: Any] {

    }
}
```

If you want to change the plist data then use this:

```
var dictionaryPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("SettingsBundle", ofType: "plist")

var dictionary = NSMutableDictionary(contentsOfFile: dictionaryPath!)

var array = dictionary?.objectForKey("key")? as NSMutableArray

//this is a label I have called player1Name
array[0] = ""

playersDictionary?.writeToFile(dictionaryPath!, atomically: true)
```

Comment: Thank you. But I guess this wouldn't allow the user to change the URL in the Settings.app?

Comment: @dislick: You can change the values

Comment: Please don't suggest `NS(Mutable)...` collection types in Swift. Use always `PropertyListSerialization` to read plist files. And you never get a mutable array with a type cast to `NSMutableArray` anyway.

Comment: @vadian: Thank you, Yes sure. I will keep it in mind