# i Want to read an Array of Dictionary with properties(btnImage+btnTitle) from Plist into TableViewCell

Tags: arrays, swift, uitableview, dictionary, plist

[Created array of dictionary having buttons.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hEyTY.png)

-created UITableviewcell.xib and .swift 
-created ib
-linked ib 
-linked dataSource and Delegates 
need help further to read my plist data and show it into tableViewCell

Comment: Did you look how to read plist in Swift? Did you look for https://stackoverflow.com/a/48140217/1801544 ?

Comment: let me check this link . thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `Decodable`, it's very simple

```
struct Section : Decodable {
    let title, icon : String
}
```

If the file is in the bundle, read it as `Data` and decode it

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "sections", withExtension: "plist")!
do {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    let result = try PropertyListDecoder().decode([Section].self, from: data)
} catch { print(error) }
```

`result` will contain an array of `Section` items

Comment: Thank yu @vadian Sir, as always you helped me. i now have to show this array of Dictionary of Button into each Cell. Guide me further Please? Also include a must to do list in your answers related to the specific topics for beginners sir, it will help us alot and learn and understand more.

Comment: cell.lblimage.image = set.title // can not convert of type string into UIImage

Comment: A string is not an image. To show an image it must be in the application bundle and you can write `cell.lblimage.image = UIImage(named: set.title)` (more likely `... named: set.icon`)