# How to fetch .plist / property list content and show in swift 4.2

Tags: ios, swift, plist, property-list

How to fetch .plist / property list  content  and show in swift 4.2

Comment: Show in which way?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get a plist as a Dictionary in Swift?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045570/how-do-i-get-a-plist-as-a-dictionary-in-swift)

Answer (score 0):

// 1. Forming resource URL of property list file

// 2. getting Data from url

// 3.serializing plist data to NSObject type classess .

```
1.guard let plistUrl = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Your property- list    file name ", withExtension: "plist"),
2.let plistData = try? Data(contentsOf: plistUrl) else { return nil }
var plistEntries: [[String: Any]]? = nil
do { 
 3. plistEntries = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: plistData,    options: [], format: nil) as? [[String: Any]]
} catch {
  print("error reading plist")
}



for property in plistEntries {
      guard let property1 = property["key-name"] as? String,
      let property2 = property["key-name"] as? NSNumber
 else { fatalError("Error reading data") }
      print("value: \(property1)")
      print("value: \(property2)")

}
```