# Simulator crashes when loading data from plist to UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, tableview

I want to show plist content into a table view, but Xcode crashed.

This is my code to get plist data :

```swift
    var tableData = [String]()

        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            self.tblMain.delegate = self
            self.tblMain.dataSource = self


            let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Province", ofType: "plist")!
            let dict = NSDictionary(contentsOfFile: path)

            tableData = dict!.object(forKey: "root") as! [String]
        }


       func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell") as! CountryNameCell
            cell.lblCountryName.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
            return cell
        }
```

This is my plist file :

[image]

Comment: post the crash .

Comment: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value . on this line : tableData = dict!.object(forKey: "root") as! [String]

Comment: dict is maybe empty, check in debugger. Better do this:  if let dict = dict { tableData = dict.object(forKey: "root") as?  [String] } else { print error here }

Comment: Answer is posted in this topic https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24045570/how-do-i-get-a-plist-as-a-dictionary-in-swift.
https://stackoverflow.com/a/24045628/9048325

Answer (score 1):

You need

```
let path = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "Province", ofType: "plist")! 
tableData  = NSArray(contentsOfFile: path) as! [String]
```

Answer (score 0):

The root object is an array, there is no ***key*** `root` (not even with uppercase `R`).

In Swift you are discouraged from using the `NSArray`/`NSDictionary` API to read and write property lists. The highly recommended API is `PropertyListSerialization`

```
let url = Bundle.main.url(forResource: "Province", withExtension: "plist")!
do {
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: url)
    tableData = try PropertyListSerialization.propertyList(from: data, format: nil) as! [String]
} catch {
    print(error)
}
```

You can even remove the `do - catch` block and `try!` reading the data as the file is in the application bundle which cannot be modified at runtime. A crash reveals a **design** mistake which can be fixed instantly.